# How should I generate secure random numbers deterministically?

Tags: random-number-generator

I have a 256-bit seed; call it P. From P, I need to derive 2<sup>19</sup> 256-bit numbers deterministically.

There's a catch, however: I want to derive them in any order. For example, I might need the 7878th number, followed by the 51st number. For that reason, deriving them with a stream cipher is inappropriate for me. Also, if one output is revealed to the attacker, it should not be possible to derive a different output.

My intuition is that I could use a hash function to derive each number, but I'm concerned that it wouldn't have the properties necessary to prevent an attacker from deriving one output from a different output.

What type of cryptographic construction should I use?

Comment: `HMAC-SHA256(seed as key, counter)` should suffice provided the seed is generated from a good randomness source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea of using a hash function to expand your seed is a reasonable one.  If you want a standardized method of doing so, try HKDF from [RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).  Specifically, I'd suggest something like the following:

```
PRK = HKDF-Extract("custom salt value", P)

output[i] = HKDF-Expand(PRK, string(i), 256/8)
```

where `"custom salt value"` is a unique string identifying your application and, where applicable, any other relevant context, so that reusing the same seed P in different contexts won't yield the same output.  (If you already know that the seed P is unique, entropy-dense and only known to your application, you can skip the HKDF-Extract step and just set `PRK = P`; see the RFC for more information.)

Of course, any other secure [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), such as the counter, feedback and double-pipeline mode KDFs from [NIST SP 800-108](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf), could be used in a similar way.

---

Alternatively, since your seed P is a random 256-bit string, and the number of outputs you require is relatively small (≪ 2<sup>64</sup>), you could simply generate your outputs using a block cipher with a 256-bit key (e.g. AES-256) in counter mode, using P as the key, e.g. like this:

```
output[i] = AES-256(P; 2*i) || AES-256(P; 2*i+1)
```

where `||` denotes bitstring concatenation, and `AES-256(P; c)` denotes the encryption of a 128-bit block encoding the counter value `c` with AES-256 using the key `P`.

Note that, since a block cipher like AES is a pseudorandom permutation, not a pseudorandom function, the output of this method will never contain duplicate blocks.  Fortunately, in your use case, this bias will not be practically detectable, since (per the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)) the expected number of random 128-bit blocks one would need to observe to actually see a duplicate is approximately 2<sup>64</sup>, i.e. far more than the number you intend to generate.

Answer (score 1):

What you request is exactly what the CTR cipher mode is doing. I'd implement it as follows:

Lets call the index $i$ for now and assume it is a 32bit Integer.
We will also use a hash algorithm $H$ which has an output size that is a multiple of 256bit.
Let's use a block cipher which has a block size of 128 and can work with a 256bit key (e.g. AES).

1. Split $H(i)$ into its $n$ 128bit parts $b_0 ... b_{n-1}$
2. Encrypt $b_0$ to $b_{n-1}$ using $P$ as the key: $e_k=C(b_k, P)$
3. Combine two subsequent ciphertexts to 256bit blocks and XOR the groups. The result is the random 256 bits. $r=(e_0 || e_1) \oplus ... \oplus (e_{n-2} || e_{n-1})$

Comment: The hash doesn't seem necessary, because a block cipher should be known-plaintext secure. Is there some reasoning behind it? You could also use $r_i = C(i||0, P) || C(i||1, P)$ where $||$ denotes concatenation provided $C$ has a 128 bit block size. Or you could use a block cipher with a 256 bit block size to do this without any concatenation.

Comment: The hash is not required. I dont know about Any padding techniques for the counter in CTR; i added the hash to be on the safe side. I frickled the 128bit cipher in there because i believe AES is the most battle-tested cipher available - and it has 128bit (yes, Rihjandel 256 would work, too, but again i'd rather be on the safe side)